# Accessing DB & shared resources w/ JAX-RS / Jersey?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I building Jersey-powered web service running in embedded Jetty 8.1.  The service has to access a database as well as shared state maintained by other threads running in the same process.

What's the recommended approach for my JAX-RS annotated resources to access DAOs, the DB, server state and other shared resources?  I'm aware I could use a singleton to provide such things, but I'm guessing there must be a better approach.

Considering that almost every JAX-RS/Jersey application is backed by a database, I'm surprised that none of the examples I've found demonstrate a good pattern for accessing the DB.

Update:  I'm getting the impression that I may want to consider a dependency injection framework, however I'm wanting to keep this simple.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what environment and what version of things you're targeting.  JEE? Spring? Glassfish or other container?  I personally am using JEE 5 on Glassfish 2 and have resorted to looking up Remote interfaces, but there are a lot of other options.

Comment: Thanks!!  My server process is just using embedded Jetty 8.1.  No Spring or JEE.

Comment: That said, I'd be game for looking into a dependency injection framework if it would be worth the overhead.  I had wanted to keep this fairly simple.

Comment: Say you wrote a traditional Servlet or jsp and deployed to Jetty, how do you access your business logic, etc. from that?

Comment: Ok, that's something to consider.  I'm actually not sure what the answer is since I'm new to Java web development, but it gives me something to look into.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would consider using JPA and/or Hibernate. It will make things much simpler and cleaner once you have your entities established. There will be a bit of a learning curve over using any current DAOs that you have already built, but in the long run I have found it to be worth it.

Here's an example...

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"createdOn","empId"})
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private Date createdOn;
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }
    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Id
    @XmlID
    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
}
```

EmployeeResource

```
@Path("/Employees")
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement 
public class EmployeeResource {
    List<Employee> employees;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getEmployee(@Context UriInfo ui, @PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("empId", new Integer(10150)));
        this.employees = criteria.list();
        return Response.ok(this).build();
    }
}
```

JSON response

```
{
  "employees":{
    "createdOn":"1330915130163",
    "empId":"10150"
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if your goal with Jersey is a RESTful API, then I could provide an example of how you can leverage the architecture above to comply with the principle of HATEOAS with minimal redundancy.

Comment: Your response addresses the mechanics of mapping persistent objects well, but that doesn't seem to be what OP is asking about.

The question appears to be more focused on the best way to share a persistent, central resource across short-lived request instances.